# Shopware 5 SEO URLs configuration with translatable attribute

Tags: configuration, shopware, shopware5

We use the following configuration in router settings for the category template:

```
{if $sCategory.attribute.attribute1}{$sCategory.attribute.attribute1}{/if}
```

`attribute1` is the slug and translatable. How do make sure its using the translated slug for the language shops?

Answer (score 0):

After getting in touch with the Shopware Support this is an existing and now known issue... https://issues.shopware.com/issues/SW-26902